# LCP time complexity analysis

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

For the approach 3 solution (divide and conquer) described in this leetcode solution article: https://leetcode.com/articles/longest-common-prefix/

Can anyone explain in details how the time complexity T(n)=2T(n/2)+O(m) ends up being O(mn)?

Comment: Because the 2 multiplies up the number of O(m)s. I don't know if this is a legitimate way to think of this (it's been too long) but if you say e.g. T(1) = t and and then work up from there you'll see that T(n) = nt + (n-1) O(m) for n powers of two. So if t is linear in m then the whole thing is linear in m, with O(nm) a sensible upper bound.

Answer (score 0):

T(n) = 2 * T(n/2) + O(m) = 2 * (2 * (T(n/4) + O(m)) + O(m)) = ...

We can find, for example n = 2^50, it will have 2^50 * T(1) + 2^50 * O(m). So the answer is O(m*n)